# サブディレクトリにもhttpアクセスできてしまう

Tags: wordpress

[WordPress を専用ディレクトリに配置する - WordPress Codex 日本語版](https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/WordPress_%E3%82%92%E5%B0%82%E7%94%A8%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AB%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

上記ページを参考に`wp`ディレクトリにwordpressを置きました。（本当は別名ですが説明上参考資料と合わせて`wp`とします。下記`example.com`も参考資料に合わせた仮の値です）

そして下記の通り行いました。

#### サイトアドレス変更

`サイトアドレス (URL) > http://example.com`

#### index.phpと.htaccessをコピー

`WordPress ディレクトリにある index.php と .htaccess ファイルを、サイトのルートディレクトリへコピー`

#### index.php編集

`ルートディレクトリの index.php ファイルを編集する`

さて、こうすると目的通り

`http://example.com` の形式でアクセスすることができましたが、`http://example.com/wp` 形式のほうもアクセス可能です。

`http://example.com/wp`の方は不要なので404を返すのがよいと思っているのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？ それともwordpressの作法的に`http://example.com/wp`形式もアクセス可能でよいものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

.htaccessということはapacheですね。

wpのディレクトリへのアクセスを拒否したいのであれば、以下のURLを参考にwpのディレクトリに対して、Allowを書かずに設定してあげればいいと思います。
http://blog.shinkaku.co.jp/archives/45972397.html

wordpressの作法はわかりませんが、不要なものは公開すべきではないと思いますので、アクセスできないようにしておいた方がよいでしょう。